# How can I get an unseen/unread notification count from the API?

Tags: javascript, php, json, getstream-io

I am using PHP. I want the unread/unseen count from PHP without using the JavaScript real time notifications library. How would I do this?

I see in the JavaScript library you get back the following information:

```
"data": {
    "deleted": "array activities or aggregated activities",
    "new": "array activities or aggregated activities",
    "unread":"int only sent for notification feeds",
    "unseen":"int only sent for notification feeds",
    "published_at":"time in iso format",
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can receive updates server-side with PHP is by requesting access to web-hooks or Amazon SQS updates.

More information about this feature is available in the documentation [here](http://getstream.io/docs/#realtime-webhooks).